# Scroll both divs on mousewheel scroll on one another

Tags: javascript

I am using this code http://jsbin.com/uhozam/1/edit?html,output for scrolling divs but when i change in code, scroll both divs on mouse wheel of one another, then issue is that mousewheel working too slow.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong using chrome on windows 7. No slowness detected

Comment: Replace example page script with ,  <script>
    (function() {
      var target1 = $("#source");
      $("#target").scroll(function() {
        target1.prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
              .prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);
      });
      var target = $("#target");
      $("#source").scroll(function() {
        target.prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
              .prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);
      });
    })();
  </script>, then you able to check difference.

Comment: I tried it on jsbin and it worked fine, i put it in jsfiddle and it also works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/arqhLkqf/ I'm using latest version of chrome on windows

Comment: Why use `.prop` when you can set `scrollTop` directly... `target.scrollTop(this.scrollTop)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var subCatContainer = $(".sub-category-container");
subCatContainer.scroll(function() {
    subCatContainer.scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/VVaEq/2/)**

Comment: Any example for vertical scrollbar divs.